# Regularity of the reparametrization map between curves

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, measure-theory, curves-and-surfaces

I am looking for a reference for the following kind of results.
Let $\Gamma$ be the space of Lipschitz curves $\text{Lip}([0,1]; \mathbb R^d)$ equipped with the sup norm. 
Let $B$ be a Borel subset of $\Gamma$ for which the following property holds: for every $\gamma \in B$ there exists a function $h_\gamma \colon [0,1] \to [0,T]$ (for some $T>0$ fixed) which is Lipschitz, non-decreasing and such that 
$$\tag{1}
\frac{dh_\gamma}{dt}(t) = 0 \Rightarrow \frac{d \gamma}{dt}(t)=0.
$$
Let $s_{\gamma}$ be (any) inverse of $h_\gamma$ ($s_\gamma$ be have jumps and there is arbitrarily defined, taking any value in the interval $(s_\gamma^-,s_\gamma^+)$); in view of the assumption (1) it turns out the the map 
$$
\tilde{\gamma}(r) := \gamma(s_\gamma(r))
$$
is well defined and continuous.
Thus we define a "reparametrization" map 
$$
R:\Gamma \to C([0,T]; \mathbb R^d)
$$
by $R(\gamma)= \tilde \gamma$. If we consider the sup norm also on $C([0,T]; \mathbb R^d)$ we can formulate the

> **Question**. Which is the regularity of $R$? Is it Borel?

I am pretty sure the result is true and well known but I cannot fined any reference nor I am able to prove it in a clean and reasonably quick way. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not quite clear to me: in these assumptions, $B\ni \gamma\mapsto s_\gamma$ could be *any* map taking $\gamma$ to some $C^1$ diffeomorphism $s_\gamma$ in any crazy irregular way, possibly having nothing to see with $\gamma$, since (1) would be automatically satisfied. Say that the function $s_\gamma$ is always either $\arctan$ or $\exp$, according whether $\gamma$ is in some ineffable set $C\subset B$ or not. Why should $R$ be any nicer than $\gamma\mapsto s_\gamma$?

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment. Yes, I have been imprecise. Let me add that I am assuming the association $\gamma \mapsto h_{\gamma}$ is Borel (between the space of Lipschitz curves in $\mathbb R^d$ and the Lipschitz maps in $\mathbb R$). Say now that I define $s_\gamma$ to be $s_\gamma(r) = \inf \{t: h_\gamma(t)>r \}$ (this should be the left inverse of $h_\gamma$). Is the corresponding association $\gamma \mapsto s_\gamma$ now at least Borel? Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then I would first consider $\gamma\mapsto h_\gamma + {1\over n}\mathrm{id}$, since I guess $s_\gamma$ can be obtained as the limit of $(h_\gamma + {1\over n}\mathrm{id})^{-1}$ for $n\to\infty$...

Comment: @PietroMajer Thanks again for your kind reply! Exactly, that was also an idea I considered but I got stuck because: 1. I am not completely sure of having an argument to prove that (inverses) of strictly monotone reparameterizations induce Borel maps between curves: do you have any references for this? 2. I had not a clear idea of how the perturbations converge (pointwise?); 3. I thought there has to be a general (well-known) argument behind (thus I came here to ask). Thanks for your valuable comments.

Comment: Shouldn't the target space of $R$ be maps from $[0,T]$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$?  Do you want to restrict the domain of $R$ to $B$?

Comment: Do you have a specific application of this sort of result in mind?  A useful trick (that may be completely unrelated to what you are interested in) is to consider $\gamma_\epsilon(t)=(\gamma(t), \epsilon t)$ as a map in $Lip([0,1, \mathbb{R}^{d+1})$.  For instance, the curves $\gamma_\epsilon$ can be parameterized by arclength in a natural way and one can study what happens as $\epsilon\to 0$ (which recovers $\gamma$ in a sense).

Comment: @Rbega Thanks for your comments! Yes, exactly, that was a typo, I fixed it. Not precise applications in mind, it is a question which arose several times and I believe there must be somewhere in the literature a general result of this kind. I am not sure of getting your hint: what is the point in considering the curve you suggest (and using arc-length there)? Thanks.

Comment: My thought was that there is a natural reparameterization of the $\gamma_\epsilon$ and this might be helpful.

Comment: For sure there is a natural reparameterization of the $\gamma_\epsilon$ but to be honest I do not see how this can be related to the Borel regularity of the reparametrization operator. In a sense, if you want, we can directly consider the curve in $\mathbb R^{d+1}$ defined by $(h, \gamma)$. But how can this be used to prove the Borel regularity of $\mathcal R$?

Comment: I have rolled back to a previous revision. Please note that vandalism of a question (by erasing virtually all its content) is considered a site violation.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Michor's book is exactly what you need, and some of his recent work involves more discussion about reparameterization.

> Michor, Peter W. [Manifolds of differentiable mappings](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/manifolds_of_differentiable_mappings.pdf). 1980.

Some of David Mumford's work also discussed the topic, a user-friedly paper might be

> Le Brigant, Alice, Marc Arnaudon, and Frédéric Barbaresco.
>   "Reparameterization invariant metric on the space of curves."
>   International Conference on Networked Geometric Science of
>   Information. Springer International Publishing, 2015.[arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06503.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest and for your references. I admit I have not a solid background in differential geometry, thus I am a bit lost in the huge book you mention. I went through the third chapter and some of the others but I did not find anything specifically related to my problem. The same for the paper you mention and another paper by Michor I have seen: it seems they do not discuss the regularity (at the level of measurability at least, which is the one I need) of the reparameterization maps. Could you be so kind to indicate me a more precise reference therein, please? Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with regularity in measurable sense, so I am sorry I cannot help in that direction.

Comment: Thus I am sorry, but I cannot accept your answer.

Comment: @user-unknown There is another source of literature that discuss natural parameterization, please see *Kurtek, Sebastian, et al. "Parameterization-invariant shape statistics and probabilistic classification of anatomical surfaces." Biennial International Conference on Information Processing in Medical Imaging. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2011.*